# Why am I getting incomplete reversed string

Tags: c++, string, stl

For the string input like this - "i.like.this.program.very.much", the output should be "much.very.program.this.like.i".

This is my code -

```
void func(string s,int n){
    vector<string>v;
    string temp="";
          for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(s[j]!='.'){
                temp+=s[j];
            }
            else{
                v.push_back(temp);
                temp="";
            }
        }
    reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<".";
    }
    cout<<"\n";   
}
```

Here 'n' is the string length and 's' is the string. I'm getting output as - "very.program.this.like.i."

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], including the shortest input (hardcoded, not via stdin) where the algorithm doesn't give expected results. Also, using a debugger to step through the code, you could probably identify the error yourself. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The else block only executes when a period is encountered. Since there is no period at the end of the string it never pushes back the final word.

```
void func(string s, int n) {
    vector<string>v;
    string temp = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (s[j] != '.') {
            temp += s[j];
        }
        else {
            v.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
    }
    // v.push_back(temp); This will push the last word / letters
    
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << ".";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(string s,int n){
    vector<string>v;
    string temp="";
          for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(s[j]!='.' || j==0){
                temp+=s[j];
            }
            else{
                v.push_back(temp);
                temp="";
            }
        }
    reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<".";
    }
    cout<<"\n";   
}
```

The statement in your code appends the character only when the current index character is a period.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the first parameters should be a constant reference to an object of the type `std::string`.

```
void func( const string &s, int n);
```

But if the compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then the first parameter is even better to make of the type `std::string_view`.

The second parameter is redundant.

The function should return the reversed string.

Instead of using a loop you could use a string stream.

In the loop the sub-string after the last symbol `'.'` is not appended to the vector.

Instead of the vector it would be better to use the container std::forward_list because you will not need to reverse its elements.

I can suggest the following function definition as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::string reverse( const std::string &s, char c = '.' )
{
    std::istringstream is( s );
    std::forward_list<std::string> list;
    
    std::string word;
    
    while ( getline( is, word, c ) ) list.push_front( word );
    
    bool first = true;
    std::string result;
    result.reserve( s.size() );     

    for ( const auto &item : list )
    {
        if ( !first ) result += c;
        else first = false;
        result += item;
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s(  "i.like.this.program.very.much" );
    
    std::cout << reverse( s ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
much.very.program.this.like.i
```